# NextCloud : Can you use encrypted drives / file level encryption?

Tags: unix, encryption, nextcloud

I am evaluating NextCloud for a solution for which I have a requirement that files cannot exist on non encrypted disks or the files themselves cannot be individually read or cached.

I have read a lot about NextCloud's encryption documentation but it does not seem to cover any aspects of whether: (a) if someone gains unauthorised access to the server itself, can the files be read or is it possible to NC to use full disk encryption with no server side caching? (b) Is it possible to lock out even devs/admins from file repositories unless they have the key - similar to accessing a remotely hosted encrypted disk image?

apols but I'm very new to the system and these are dealbreakers for evaluation

Comment: aslong the server is booted and someone gains the credentials, tgey can access the data directly, so why should they then consider anything else?

Comment: @djdomi this is what I'm intending to combat. I.e; the files on the server are encrypted so that even the developer cannot view them, only when a user comes in and adds a password via the web-client, will the files be decrypted